# Indices should either be on CPU... error on google collab

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following command on google collab for an AI Art generator:

```
import accelerate


accelerate.notebook_launcher(training_function, args=(text_encoder, vae, unet))
```

But I keep getting the same error every time:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-7e0131ac8691> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import accelerate
----> 2 accelerate.notebook_launcher(training_function, args=(text_encoder, vae, unet))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_ddpm.py in add_noise(self, original_samples, noise, timesteps)
    253     ) -> Union[torch.FloatTensor, np.ndarray]:
    254 
--> 255         sqrt_alpha_prod = self.alphas_cumprod[timesteps] ** 0.5
    256         sqrt_alpha_prod = self.match_shape(sqrt_alpha_prod, original_samples)
    257         sqrt_one_minus_alpha_prod = (1 - self.alphas_cumprod[timesteps]) ** 0.5

RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your PyTorch version and accelerate version are compatible and up to date. Maybe you will need to downgrade PyTorch